# Looking for stock dataset with symbols

Tags: dataset, recommendation-engine

Hi Am looking for a dataset where I can get all the global stock names and there symbols (EG: Apple Inc - AAPL). My first priority is to get Indian stock names and symbols. I looked a lot can't find. umm if it's not there can I parse/crawl anyhow to create that dataset
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as Indian stocks are concerned go to NSE/BSE website and download bhavcopy. you can find all tickers.